# Laravel: Allow multiple email in vue js email validation

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

We have module called "Customer". When create is clicked, one of the field named Contact Email(data type of contact email is text).

In one of our module, you can send the record thru email(using the contact email in Customer).

Currently, you can send the record to 1 customer but now we will have enhancement where you can send the record to multiple customer.

**Customer Example**

```
xxxx@gmail.com, yyyy@yopmail.com
```

In backend, I will use foreach to separate the 2 emails

Question: Is it possible to allow multiple emails when the validation is email?

**Vue**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" name="contact_email" v-model="$v.contact_email.$model" class="form-control">
        <div v-if="$v.contact_email.$dirty">
            <p class="error" v-if="!$v.contact_email.email">please enter a valid email.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label>Website</label>
        <input type="text" name="contact_website" v-model="contact_website" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Validation**

```
validations: {
    contact_email: {
        email
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and it did not work?

In your validations, you are checking if the email is valid, and not if the email is unique, or quantity, so if you don`t have any custom validation, by the logic it's yes.

And if your email validation rule is checking also the uniqueness of email, I guess you can just over-right it.